# Subtracting double gives wrong result

Tags: c++, double, subtraction

I am trying to get the decimal part from the double and this is my code to get the decimal part

```
double  decimalvalue = 23423.1234-23423.0;
0.12340000000040163
```

But after the subtraction I am expecting decimalvalue to be 0.1234 but I get 0.12340000000040163. Please help me to understand this behavior and if there is any workaround for it.

Comment: There are an infinite number of real values but only 64 bits in a double.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

[Wikipedia: IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

There are a finite number of values you can specify in a floating point number, but an infinite number of floating point numbers in the represented range.

Some floating point numbers therefore cannot be represented exactly in any floating/double style data type.

The typical way to handle your specific problem is to avoid a direct equality comparison, but rather do an epsilon test: See if the expected and computed values are within some small number (compared to the values being subtracted), called *epsilon*, of each other.

Indirectly related is the concept of [Machine Epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon), worth having a look at for a complete understanding

Comment: Epsilon should be appropriate for the magnitude of the numbers being compared.

Comment: For beginners, "Nearly equal" is much worse than `==`. Learn how floating-point works; don't try to hide it with hacks that break transitivity.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rounding error. In base ten you cannot perfectly represent 1/3 in a given number of digits (say 15). In base 2 there are a lot more things you can not represent, 0.1234 happens to be one of them. The precision depends on the scale, but it's about 15 decimal digits for a double. I would suggest taking a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point for more details on floating point numbers.

If you are trying to make a base 10 system (like a human used calculator for instance) and you need exact results you should use BCD.

Comment: "...you cannot represent with *finite precision*."

Comment: Lol, I was just about to modify that myself :P